# How to convince chrome(browser) to show the download file dialog?

Tags: wcf, google-chrome, browser, mime-types

How to convince chrome(browser) to show the download file dialog while downloading a JSON content?

With the following headers chrome renders the JSON  directly on the screen. Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, you only have to set the content disposition on the server end,

```
WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "application/json";
WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition: attachment;  filename=" + fileName + ".json");
```